# Create new classes by Tooling API

Tags: rest-api, api, tooling-api, tooling

I have a problem with creation **new APEX classes** by using #Tooling API.
In first scenario, I want to **create one class**:
Steps:

1. Create `MetadataContainer`
2. By using `MetadataContainer` Id, create `ApexClassMember` (with `Metadata`, `FullName`, `Body` and `MetadataContainerId`)
3. Create `ContainerAsyncRequest`, related to `MetadataContainer`
   **Everything is works fine for create and update a class.**

Second scenario, I want to **create some classes**:

1. Create `MetadataContainer`
2. 1. By using `MetadataContainer` Id, create `ApexClassMember` (with `Metadata`, `FullName`, `Body` and `MetadataContainerId`)
   2. By using `MetadataContainer` Id, create additional `ApexClassMember` (with same set of fields)
3. Create `ContainerAsyncRequest`, related to `MetadataContainer`

If the classes are exists, everything is fine, all classes are updated.
**BUT**, if there some class(es) is(are) new, first class will be created but rest will fail with very strange error: "`duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>`".

Any help is appreciated